# React TS connect wallet

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ethers.js

I have current code working as it should but on pc's where user have metamask extension. Currently problem is when user is on mobile and clicking on connect button nothing happends even if have metamask application on mobile. Any simple solution or advice to get this working on all devices?

Code:

```
import { Contract, ethers } from "ethers";
import MarketContract from "./Market.json";
import blockies from "blockies";

declare global {
    interface Window {
      ethereum?: any;
    }
}

const contractAddress = "0x";
const desiredNetworkID = 11155111;

export default async function getContract(): Promise<{
  contract: Contract;
  userAddress: string | null;
  connectWallet: () => Promise<{ address: string | null; identicon: string | null; balance: string | null }>;
}> {
  const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider((window as any).ethereum);
  let userAddress: string | null = null;

  const network = await provider.getNetwork();
  if (network.chainId !== desiredNetworkID) {
    alert('Please change to the Sepolia network')
    throw new Error('Please change to the Sepolia network');
  }
  
  try {
    const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();
    if (accounts.length > 0) {
      userAddress = accounts[0];
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching accounts: ", error);
  }

  let signer = provider.getSigner();
  const contract = new ethers.Contract(
    contractAddress,
    MarketContract.abi,
    signer
  );

  const connectWallet = async (): Promise<{ address: string | null; identicon: string | null; balance: string | null;  }> => {
    try {
      if (!window.ethereum) {
        throw new Error('Please connect to MetaMask');
      }
      
      await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });

      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const network = await provider.getNetwork();

      if (network.chainId !== desiredNetworkID) {
        alert('Please change to the Sepolia network')
        throw new Error('Please change to the Sepolia network');
      }

      const accounts = await provider.listAccounts();

      if (accounts.length > 0) {
        const address = accounts[0];
  
        const identicon = blockies({ seed: address.toLowerCase(), size: 8, scale: 16 }).toDataURL();
  
        const balanceBigNumber = await provider.getBalance(address);
        const balance = ethers.utils.formatEther(balanceBigNumber);

        if(address){
          const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/cryptoserver/api/users/login/${address}`);
          const data = await response.json();
          const token = data.token;
          localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        }
    
        return { address, identicon, balance };
      } else {
        return { address: null, identicon: null, balance: null };
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error connecting wallet: ", error);
      return { address: null, identicon: null, balance: null };
    }
  };

  return {
    contract,
    userAddress,
    connectWallet,
  };
}
```

Best regards

Comment: From what I understand you have the wallet app installed but you're using a different browser to access your app. On mobile you can only connect with a wallet if you're using the built-in browser from the wallet app. You can't access the app or the wallet from an external browser app like chrome/firefox.

Comment: Yes this is my code for connecting to wallet currently everything working fine from pc browsers where I have metamask extension, currently prolem is that I cant trigger the mobile metamask app on button click? Is there any simple solution for achive this?

Comment: what browser are you using on mobile?

Comment: the chrome, but I also have metamask application on mobile but it dont trigger anything..

Comment: You can't 'trigger' the metamask app from an external browser. You need to access your app directly from your metamask built-in browser

Comment: Any example link or code update based on my code for simplier solution that can cover all possible scenarios?